# IIS Express help command not showing usage options

Tags: command-line-arguments, iis-express

Has anyone experienced iisexpress.exe from command line not showing help/usage? I've tried typing `iisexpress.exe /?` and other known variations of help, but "usage" help is never shown. As for environment, I'm using Windows 7 Pro 64bit, with vs 2010-2013 installed and .net frameworks 4, 4.5, 4.5.1, and 4.6.1. Thanks for any help.

Comment: There is dedicate page at http://IIS.net.